# Spring Boot 起動するとユーザ名とパスワードを求められる

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring Bootを勉強しようと始めたのですが、
「Springスタータプロジェクト」を作成して、実行した後、ブラウザからアクセスするとログイン認証が来てしまいます。ユーザ名とパスワードが分からず先に進めません。

現象
「サーバlocalhostがユーザ名とパスワードを要求しています。サーバの報告によると、これはXDBからの要求です。」
このメッセージが出て、ユーザ名とパスワードを求められてしまいます。127.0.0.1でも同じです。

環境
spring-tool-suite-3.9.8
JDK12
Windows10
Microsoft Edge

実行
プロジェクトの実行で「SpringBootアプリケーション」で実行
URL:localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDBということは、そのマシンにOracle DBをインストールしていませんか？おそらく、Oracle DBと同時に入るアプリケーションサーバーが8080番ポートで既に起動していて、ログインを要求しているのではないかと思います。Spring Bootはポート競合で起動していないかもしれませんね。なので、Oracleを停止してから、Spring Bootを起動してみて下さい。

Comment: 有難うございます！
おっしゃる通りOracleをインストールしていて、
サービスを停止したら正常に動きました。
本当に助かりました。 ちなみにTOMCATのポートを変えようと思っていますが
どこをいじったら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: `conf/server.xml`の`<Connector port="8080"`のところです。

Comment: あ、Spring Bootだから`application.properties(yml)`ですね。

Comment: application.propertiesのnio.http.port=8081に変更したらうまく動きました。ありがとうございました。（＾＾

Comment: 解決したら回答を[クローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)して下さい〜

Comment: Spring Bootの標準的な設定プロパティ名は `server.port`([78.3 Change the HTTP Port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-change-the-http-port))です。